# Can't get XDebug to work with Netbeans

Tags: php, xdebug, netbeans-8

Please do not close, would really like some help here.

I know I know, this question has been posted before, but I am at my wit's end here.

I have tried literally every single list of settings I could find for my php.ini file.

Here's what I'm using...

- Windows 10
- Netbeans 8.0.2
- WAMP 3.0.6 (64-bit)
- PHP 7.0.1

Ok, here me out and here's my frustration. I've actually gotten the debugger to work before. However, if I leave my computer for a while (overnight for example), and come back to it (doesn't go to sleep, no hibernation, no shut down), the debugger no longer works. Absolutely NOTHING has changed. Everything is left open, it is left completely untouched, but now the debugger no longer works.

I have spent the past 4-5 days pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. I have done reboots, restarted WAMP and Netbeans, tried various settings in my php.ini file and no luck. I don't know what I did before that got it working. This is the 3rd time I've gotten it working and then it stopping for no reason. And I honestly can not say what got it working the previous times.

Here are the php.ini settings that I got working that no longer work.

```
zend_extension ="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.4.1-7.0-vc14-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.profiler_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = on
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "c:/wamp64/tmp"
```

I checked the error logs and found this.

XDebug could not open the remote debug file 'c:/wamp64/tmp/xdebug/xdebug_remot.log'.

I didn't want to post this question, but I've tried everything I can think of.

Oh and to be clear, when I say no longer working, I mean, it gets hung up on "Waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug)".

Really frustrated, so I appreciate any and all help. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Does the 'c:/wamp64/tmp/xdebug/' directory exist?   Does the  'c:/wamp64/tmp/xdebug/xdebug_remot.log'. file exist?  is it marked read only?

Comment: It didn't before, and it worked. It does now, and still no cigar.

Comment: And this is the frustrating part, I got it working. This time, it was by changing the default browser in netbeans. I changed it to internet explorer and then back to chrome. Chrome is what it was set on before. This entire combination is rather temperamental and I'd really like to know why that change "fixed" the problem. Mind you, this isn't the first time I changed the default browser in netbeans either.

Comment: And now that I've closed the debugging session, it no longer works unless I switch the browsers again. Starting to think it's an issue with Chrome...

Comment: Possibly. Another possibility is the system's registry is getting.. uh funky.